# gnumeric set date and number format at same time?

Tags: format, gnumeric

Im using this two command for separate for set date and number format respectly

```
     LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8    gnumeric



      LC_NUMERIC="pe"  gnumeric
```

But I dont know how I could do in same time

please help me

Comment: Have you tried simply chaining both? i.e. `LC_TIME=en_AU.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC="pe"  gnumeric`

Comment: I try this but dont work